# magento checkout: change shipping price

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

Scenario:
Change shipping price using variable parsed by design during checkout.
I need to change the final shipping price using some variables sent by phtml checkout.

Eg.

```
Shipping method 1: cost 33$

Shipping method 2: cost 23$

Shipping method 3: cost 10$
     special packaging checkbox (y/n) + 10$ (set it as yes for this example)
     assicuration:
```

I've inserted manually this checkbox, just in design but I need to increment final price and add a simple label that include this on shipment

total should be

```
shipment total                                    20$
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this, you will need to write your own Shipping Module.  There is a wiki article [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/how-to/create-shipping-method-module) with instructions, otherwise there are many good blog posts on the process.  I would recommend that you use one of the existing Magento shipping modules (e.g. `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrate`) as an example and then just extend the `collectRates` method to test for the value of your variable.